# Cake PHP 2.x Model validation is called twice

Tags: validation, cakephp, model, controller, cakephp-2.x

When I try to validate data from controller in my Model, then the errors occur two times in the `invalidFields` array, but I don't understand why.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::import('Vendor','Excel');

class ServicedesksController extends AppController{
    public $uses = array("CustomerInformation");

    public function uploadData(){
    $this->layout = 'index';

    if($this->request->is('post')){ 
        $safeData = array('name' => 'testkun', 'kkz' => 'bae');
        $this->CustomerInformation->set($safeData);
        if($this->CustomerInformation->validates()){
            print_r("successful");
        }else{
            print_r($this->CustomerInformation->invalidFields());
            print_r("not successful");
        }
    }

}
```

And here's my Model code:

```
<?php

class CustomerInformation extends AppModel{
    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
             'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
             'message' => 'Minimum length of 8 is required'
         ),
         'kkz' => array(
             'rule-1' => array(
                 'rule' => '/^[A-Z]{3}$/i',
                 'message' => 'Only letters allowed'
             ),
             'rule-2' => array(
                 'rule' => 'checkDuplicate',
                 'message' => 'There is still an existing entry for this kkz',
                 'last' => false

             )
         )
     );

     public function checkDuplicate($check){
        $existingCount = $this->find('count', array(
             'conditions' => $check
        ));
        return $existingCount == 0;

    }
}
```

When I execute `uploadData`, `invalidFields` contains

```
Array ( 
    [name] => Array ( 
        [0] => Minimum length of 8 is required 
        [1] => Minimum length of 8 is required 
)
```

Why I got this error twice? I tried already to rename the fields, reduce the validation rules and test with different Models and Controllers/Consoles. But all have the same behaviour.

I could not find any bug report about this. I would be pleased if anybody could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the cookbook:

> The `validates` method invokes the `invalidFields` method which populates the `validationErrors` property of the model. The `invalidFields method` also returns that data as the result:

```
$errors = $this->ModelName->invalidFields(); // contains validationErrors array
```

> The validation errors list is not cleared between successive calls to `invalidFields()`. So if you are validating in a loop and want each set of errors separately don’t use `invalidFields()`. Instead use `validates()` and access the `validationErrors` model property.

Therefore, you should call:

```
print_r($this->CustomerInformation->validationErrors);
```

instead of

```
print_r($this->CustomerInformation->invalidFields());
```

See [Validating Data from the Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html#validating-data-from-the-controller).